# How does JSX differentiate props, event handlers and custom props?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Given this example component:

```
<SampleComponent
    className={'container'}
    onClick={componentClickHandler}
    someCustomProp={123}
/>
```

How does JSX know what kind of prop each "attribute" is?

P.S. I'm new to React and JSX and apologize if I got any of the terms wrong.

Comment: as far as I know react doesnt differentiate between props. React just passes a set of pre-defined props like `className` and `aria-label` (if available at that component) as attributes to the DOM element. Hint: you don't have to put strings into curly braces in react.

Comment: What do you mean 'kind of props'? At this point it is mostly just a list of key-value pairs. The system code just picks out specific keys down the line (like dom- or event related attributes) and applies them the the created dom elements.

Comment: thanks for the input! based on what you're saying, can I say that React simply maps camelCase props into lowercase HTML attributes? Is there any documentation that explains how this works?